# Casting CLR unsigned integer datatype in Dynamics Ax 2009

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2009

I am getting error in Dynamics Ax 2009 when I try to set a variable of CLR type `UInt32` like in the following example:

```
System.UInt32 duration;
;

duration = 50; 

// Error : Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'System.UInt32'.
// Ax explicit conversion might exist; use System.Convert.
```

So I tried

```
duration = (System.Uint32) 50;

// Error: The table is out of range or does not exist.
```

and finally

```
duration = System.Convert.ToUInt32(20); // Error: Syntax error.
```

Any solution to assign value to variable duration?

Thanks in advance for help.
Kashif.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

`duration = System.Convert::ToUInt32(20);`

as `ToUInt32` is a static method of `System.Convert`

Example:

```
static void TestJob(Args _args)
{
    System.UInt32 duration;
    str tmp;
    ;

    duration = System.Convert::ToUInt32(20);
    tmp = duration.ToString();
    info(strfmt("%1", tmp));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.